# SYSTEM_USER in Azure Hybrid Connection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-webapps

I'm connecting to a SQL Server 2017 using an Azure Hybrid connection. My connection string is

```
Server=server,port;Database=database;User ID=read-only_user;Password=read-only_user_password;
```

The .NET C# web app connects successfully and runs queries but if I run

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER, SUser_SName();
```

they both return SA. I've tried different credentials to no avail.

When I leave the credentials out the connection fails, no surprise, so I know they're being used. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path that is routing your server locally and the ip is visible from your address

The following scenario works:
`Application code -> GetHostByName("10.4.5.6") -> Resolves to 127.0.0.3 -> Connect("127.0.0.3") -> Hybrid Connection -> on-prem host`

The following scenario doesn't work:
`Application code -> Connect("10.4.5.6") -> ?? -> No route to host`

Comment: If I'm getting a result from the on-premise server wouldn't that mean that the connectivity is not an issue?  This seems like an authentication glitch.